# Active MQ VirtualTopic - messages stay enqueued even if dispatched to all defined/linked queues

Tags: activemq-classic

Using Active MQ 5.15.4 and following the doc from http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html, when sending to a VirtualTopic, the messages get sent to all connected queues, but they never get dequeued from the virtual topic where they were sent.

Do we need to manually clean the virtual topic?

What is the reason of having the messages kept in the topic? Is it that they can be re-sent later on? But when a new queue gets linked to the virtual topic, all existing enqueued messages are not sent to it.

Have not tested this, but are the messages in the connected queues respecting the persistence flag for the message sent in the virtual topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no consumer on the Virtual Topic itself then the only messages retained are the one's placed on the subscription queues for the Virtual Topic consumers.  For example if you send to VirtualTopic.FOO and there are no subscriptions on that Topic or the named Virtual Topic consumer queues such as Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.FOO then the message would be completely discarded.  If there was some consumer on the consumer queue at some point then messages sent to the Topic are then forwarded to the Queue but the Topic itself retains nothing.

If there are consumers on the Virtual Topic itself they would get messages sent to them or held for them up to the configured pending message limit etc etc.

The Consumer Queues will respect the persistent value specified by the MessageProducer that sent them.

Comment: Thanks Tim!  My concern was based on the fact that the active mq ui shows no Dequeued messages, but the Enqueued ones keeps increasing, but messages were being sent to the related queues (and dequeued there if there were consumers connected). So based on your comment, messages will never stay in a Virtual Topic if there are no consumer defined for the topic itself, even if the Dequeued stays are zero and Enqueued keeps increasing?

Comment: That should be the case, enqueue counts on Topics are not a reliable metric for what is going on there as Topics can have many subscribers that all get a copy, and if none are present the message if effectively discarded.